# Tools for Interactive Charts in.NET

Tags: .net, charts, interactive

Our requirement is to show a Grid with tabular data and the corresponding graph in the same page. Both the graph and grid are tightly coupled and should be interactive i.e., if user updates the bars in the graph, data in the grid should be updated and vice versa.

We are looking for some tools through which this can be achieved.

Does anyone has come across such kind of requirement and used any tools for the same?

Thanks,
Sravanthi

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://goo.gl/KUmLs2) should help you out. There are some solid options listed. Telerik being the best in my opinion. As far as updating between the 2 it could be done with something like AJAX and JavaScript.